# Tcl : Guaranteed evaluation sequence of a boolean expression?

Tags: conditional-statements, tcl, expression

Let's say I have a conditional Tcl expression that is a boolean combination of steps.

1. Will the expression always be evaluated left to right (excluding parentheses)?
2. If the expression becomes true will the rest of the evaluation stop?

I have this piece of code that parses a file and conditionally replaces stuff in the lines.

```
set fp [ open "file" ]
set data [ read $fp ]
close $fp
foreach line [ split $data \n ] {
    if { $enable_patch && [ regsub {<some_pattern>} $line {<some_other_pattern>} line ]} {
        puts $outfp $line
        <do_some_more_stuff>
    }
}
```

So my issue here is that unless `enable_patch` is true, I don't want the line to be modified. Now my test shows that the code is deterministic in Tcl 8.5 on Linux. But I am wondering if this would break under other conditions/ versions/ OSes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `||` and `&&` operators are "short-circuiting" operators in TCL.  That means you can rely on them being evaluated left-to-right, and that evaluation will stop as soon as the value of the expression is known.

Comment: Tcl evaluates all parts of an expression _strictly_ left-to-right, and guarantees that `&&` and `||` (and `? :`) will short-circuit in the conventional way. You can get into trouble if you don't put your expression in braces, as that can give you multiple substitution rounds; the fix is to put the expression in braces and that's highly recommended anyway as it makes the code much more efficient (by enabling better bytecode compilation behind the scenes).